# Solving non Homogenous DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to solve the below problem using the method of variation of parameters, but I am interested in solving the problem without using that. (I know how to solve if $f(x)$ on R.H.S. is $\sin(x)$ then assume $y = A\sin(x) + B\cos(x)$, if it's $e^{mx}$ then assume $y = A e^{mx}$ and solve for $A$ and $B$.) I wanted to solve it using first assuming some $y = f(x)$ and eliminating constants by plugging the function back to differential equation.

> $$y'' + 6y' + 9y = \frac{e^{3x}}{x^2}$$

I even want to know a generalised method for how to solve if $f(x)$ on R.H.S. is $\ln(x)$ or $\frac1x$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters